# What will be the Turing machine to show that the function $T(n) = n$ is time constructible?

Tags: complexity-theory

Specifically, we need a Turing machine that on input $1^n$ outputs binary representation of $n$ on output tape in $O(n)$ time. I am not able to get any thing better than trivial $O(n \log n)$ time. Any hints or solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly have the right machine: just implement a binary counter and increment it once for each character of the input.

What you need is a more sophisticated analysis of the running time. You've presumably reasoned that the counter will end up with $\log n$ bits, you need to increment it $n$ times and each increment could change all the bits, so there are $O(n\log n)$ operations.  This is completely correct but you can do better.

Suppose the current value of the counter is even. How many bits do you have to change to increment the counter? How often do you need to change more than two bits? How often do you have to change all $\log n$ bits to increment the counter?

Comment: @VimalRajSharma You're welcome -- glad to be of help. You might consider up-voting and accepting the answer. There's more information about this in our [tour] but the quick summary is that up-voting is the Stack Exchange way of saying "thanks!" and accepting an answer says that it solved your problem. If somebody writes a better answer, you can change your mind about which one to accept.